# Autopopulate textarea from database based on dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to autopopulate a textarea with values from a (wordpress) database based on the value selected in a select menu. Basically the select menu contains a list of teams and I wish to populate my textarea with names of the players from the selected team.

The problem is that I need to convert the selected text to a php variable in order to use it to query the database. Like so:

PHP

```
$usergroups = $mingleforum->get_usergroups();

$team_title = $_GET['usergroup'];
$team_id = get_page_by_title( $team_title );
$players = get_users( array (
                'meta_key' => 'team-meta',
                'meta_value' => $team_id
            ));
```

JS

```
jQuery(function(jQuery){

jQuery('#usergroup').change(function() {

  jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:8888/dev_wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mfgroups&mingleforum_action=usergroups&do=add_user_togroup",
      data: { usergroup: jQuery(this).find(':selected').text() }
  }).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );

    });

   });


});
```

UPDATE: corrected the url (based on @jterry 's comment) and no longer getting error (although it still isn't working)
I am getting the following error: 
`GET http://localhost:8888/dev_wordpress/wp-admin/wpf-addusers.php?usergroup=Coq+and+Bulldog 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: `wpf-addusers.php` doesn't exist at that path. Specify the absolute URI and you'll at least make it past the `404`.

Comment: thanks, I didn't even think about that. I'm geting the "Data Saved:" alert now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the points! :D

`wpf-addusers.php` doesn't exist at that path. Specify the absolute URI and you'll at least make it past the `404` error. Also, it looks like your `url` parameter has `""` on both sides of the variable - you just need one on each side.

**EDIT**

To access the variable you're looking for (`usergroup`) to use in your PHP script, you can use `$_GET['usergroup']`. From there, you can use it as you see fit or insert it as the `value` of an input element.

If you use the value in an `input` element, be sure to use [`htmlentities`](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) to properly escape the value.

Comment: Definately helpful but it doesn't actually do anything except get past the error. I'm trying to get the value from `GET http://localhost:8888/dev_wordpress/wp-admin/wpf-addusers.php?usergroup=Coq+and+Bulldog` i.e. "Coq and Bulldog" so it can work in my php function and populate the textarea with the player names. The double- double quotes were just a typo from copying and pasting into the editor here.

Comment: I was trying to save it as a variable to use in the database query like this `$team_title = $_GET['usergroup'];` but I'm obviously doing it wrong because I get nothing when I echo $team_title.

Comment: In your `wpf-addusers.php`, try `var_dump($_GET)`. That will at least tell you what you have to work with.

Comment: Its not passing a value: `array(3) { ["page"]=> string(8) "mfgroups" ["mingleforum_action"]=> string(10) "usergroups" ["do"]=> string(16) "add_user_togroup" }` which is odd as it was passing a value when I got the error message so my problem does seem to be with the url. You are very kind to help me with all this, even if for points :) wish I could give you more but I want to make sure the answer is right before I check it off.

Comment: It's no trouble... open your browser console and check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XZayd/)... see if you can hard-code the `usergroup` variable like I've done there. You'll notice that the `usergroup` value is successfully being transferred as `test`.

Comment: Apparently the problem was ajax in Wordpress as it has its own Ajax API. I got it working on a test page so at least I know how to do it now. All that's left is to learn how to use the API. I appreciate your help.